# Issues when creating a shared pointer of condition variable

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, condition-variable

I apologize if this has been asked before, I was not able to find it online.  Why does the compiler think that I am trying to call the copy constructor of `std::condition_variable`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

class A {
 public:
  A() = default;
  A(A&&) = default;
  A& operator=(A&&) = default;
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};
int main() {

  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable>> m;
  m.push_back(std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>(std::condition_variable{}));

  // no complains here
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> m_a;
  m_a.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(A{}));

  return 0;
}
```

The error I get is that I am trying to use the deleted copy constructor of `std::condition_variable`..  I guess what I am trying to ask is why the move constructor is not called with that invocation of `make_shared`

Comment: The arguments for `make_shared` are used fo constructing the object. In your case you are passing it a temporary which matches the copy constructor signature.

Comment: @Arunmu Actually, it matches move constructor signsture

Comment: @UldisK There is no `move constructor` for condition_variable.

Comment: @UldisK if the copy constructor is explicitly defined as deleted, the move constructor will not be implicitly declared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In

```
std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>(std::condition_variable{})
```

`std::condition_variable{}` creates a `std::condition_variable`.  This means that `std::make_shared` is going to construct it's internal `std::condition_variable` with the passed parameter which invokes the copy constructor.  If you need a default constructed `std::condition_variable` then you can use

```
std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>()
```

Comment: Why not the move constructor?

Comment: @Curious It does not have a move constructor.

Comment: that's right! I dont know why I confused move assignment with the move construction

Comment: @Curious It's not move assignable as well :)

Comment: @Arunmu it has to be, how else can you have a vector of condition variables?  At least I'm pretty sure it is

Comment: @Curious per [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and the standard it is not move assignable as well.

Comment: So technically you are not allowed to have a vector of condition_variables?  That is news to me............

Comment: @Curious I don't believe so.  I suppose you could if you do not need dynamic growth and instead reserve the size you need and then use `emplace_back` to add the `condition_variable`s

Comment: Wait I think the reserve and `emplace_back` trick might not work, since space is allocated right when the vector calls `new` and that will call the default constructor for `condition_variable`s which means that any subsequent insert will move the object into place right?  `emplace_back`ing is quite similar to `push_back`ing with an rvalue

Comment: I think the only way it would be possible would be if a vector allocates the right amount of memory and does a placement new.  But that does not sound quite right..

Comment: @Arunmu and NathanOliver Maybe I should ask this as another question?

Comment: @Curious As long as you do not out grow the capacity of the vector it has no reason to allocate more space.  So if you need 50 variables you call `reserve` with 50 and then you can `emplace_back` 50 variables without a reallocation.  Not sure if the standard guarantees `size == capacity()` but it should work on any sane implementation.

Comment: @Curious Another question about that would be great.  I find nothing with a quick google search.

Comment: But when you do a `reserve` you are essentially calling the `new` operator to allocate memory for `x` objects on the heap right?  that would call the default consturctor for those objects?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Good food for though for another question ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232576/why-is-a-condition-variable-not-moveassignable :)

Comment: @Curious: `reserve` is not enough, as *resize* code has to handle the case where there is not enough space, the only way is at the construction.

Comment: @NathanOliver That doesn't work, because whether or not `emplace_back()` or `reserve()` has to move/copy items is a run time decision, not a compile time decision, so code has to be generated that can move/copy the items held.  The only way to put a non-moveable/non-copyable type into a `vector` is at `vector` construction time when using the `explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());` constructor, as that uses default construction to put elements into the `vector`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the compiler think that I am trying to call the copy constructor of std::condition_variable?`

That's what the compiler will use when you call

```
std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>(std::condition_variable{})
```

`std::make_shared` uses any constructor that will take the arguments passed to it. In this case, the copy constructor is the one.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared:

> **args**   -   list of arguments with which an instance of T will be constructed.

Comment: Why not the move constructor?

Comment: @Curious, looks like you got your answer to the above question.