# Why is a condition_variable not MoveAssignable

Tags: c++, c++11, move, condition-variable

Why is a `condition_variable` not MoveConstructible (as per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)?  That prohibits inclusion in lots of containers (eg. `std::unordered_map`) that move things around.

This forces people to use a `unique_ptr` which incurs one extra heap allocation, which things like `make_shared` were built to solve.  Also if one doesn't have a pool allocator this can become quite inefficient.

Comment: Possibly it would have been too burdensome to make it thread safe.  You would not want a notify to happen during a move of the variable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Aren't all functions in the interface of a `condition_variable` thread safe anyway?  I'm just thinking about why that should have been a problem

Comment: I think it just does not make any sense. Consider a case where a condition variable is in wait state and another thread copied it. What should be the state of the copied condition variable ? If you say it should be like in its default constructed state then again copying really made no sense. Also, it depends on whether the native condition variable structure (used inside `std::condition_variable`) say `pthread_cond_t` is allowed to be copied without invoking UB or not.

Comment: A `std::condition_variable` is not CopyConstructible, MoveConstructible, CopyAssignable, MoveAssignable. Are you particularly interested in knowing why it is not MoveAssignable, or do you want to know "why" for all of those traits?

Comment: It is a synchronization construct that multiple threads are (potentially) using simultaneously.  How could you move it safely?  E.g., suppose it directly contains a spinlock.  Some thread is spinning on a given _address in your process address space_ and you're going to move it out from under it?

Comment: `condition_variable` was born here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#condition  It is not an easy read, but is fairly complete. It refers to `condition_variable` as `cond_var`. This is nothing but a rename that happened during standardization. "Born here" is an exaggeration. `condition_variable` is the product of existing practice over decades prior to C++11. There was a deliberate decision to not be inventive because this is a very tricky and low-level API. `condition_variable_any` is an example of a higher-level API that can be built on top of the lower API.

Comment: Most of the things Jonathan Wakely wrote in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14304618/2756719) about `std::mutex` apply mutatis mutandis to `condition_variable` too.

Answer (score 7):

`condition_variable` is a synchronization construct that multiple threads are (potentially) using simultaneously. (In fact, that's its purpose.) How could you move it safely? E.g., suppose it directly contains a spinlock. Some thread is spinning on a given address in your process address space and you're going to move the object out from under it?

Any kind of user-mode synchronization construct can't be moved.  The thing that does the actual synchronization needs a fixed address.  You could force the object to do all of its real work on a heap-allocated object that wouldn't be moved - and there you go right to the indirection to the heap that you wanted to avoid.  (Kernel-mode synchronization constructs can be moved:  you've got a handle to some OS thing.  But they're much more expensive to *use*.)

They can't be copied either - because what would that mean?

It just has to be this way.  Your design must account for it, that's all.

(And I don't really understand the second paragraph of your question.  `make_shared` was built to make ref counts less expensive and don't have anything to do with moving stuff around.  A pool allocator may or may not improve any particular situation, much less this one, and you won't know unless you measure it.)